# Scipy.optimize.curve_fit won't fit cosine power law

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting

For several hours now, I have been trying to fit a model to a (generated) dataset as a casus for a problem I've been struggling with. I generated datapoints for the function f(x) = A*cos^n(x)+b, and added some noise. When I try to fit the dataset with this function and curve_fit, I get the error

```
./tester.py:10: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power
return Amp*(np.cos(x))**n + b
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py:690: OptimizeWarning: Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated  category=OptimizeWarning)
```

The code I'm using to generate the datapoints and fit the model is the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure, show, rc, plot

def f(x, Amp, n, b):

    return np.real(Amp*(np.cos(x))**n + b)

x = np.arange(0, 6.28, 0.01)
randomPart = np.random.rand(len(x))-0.5
fig = figure()
sample = f(x, 5, 2, 5)+randomPart
frame = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

frame.plot(x, sample, label="Sample measurements")

popt, pcov = curve_fit(f, x, sample, p0=(1,1,1))

modeldata = f(x, popt[0], popt[1], popt[2])
print(modeldata)
frame.plot(x, modeldata, label="Best fit")

frame.legend()
frame.set_xlabel("x")
frame.set_ylabel("y")

show()
```

The noisy data is shown - see the image below.

[image: No fit is possible]

Does any of you have a clue of what's going on? I suspect it has something to do with the power law going into the complex domain, as the real part of the function is [nowhere divergent](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(cos(x))%5Ey%20from%20x%3D-10%20to%20x%3D10,%20from%20y%3D1%20to%20y%3D5). I have tried returning only the real part of the function, setting realistic bounds in curve_fit and using a numpy array instead of a python list for p0 already as well. I'm running the latest version of scipy available to me, scipy 0.17.0-1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is the following:

```
>>> (-2)**1.1
(-2.0386342710747223-0.6623924280875919j)
>>> np.array(-2)**1.1
__main__:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power
nan
```

Unlike native python floats, numpy doubles usually refuse to take part in operations leading to complex results:

```
>>> np.sqrt(-1)
__main__:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt
nan
```

As a quick workaround I suggest adding an `np.abs` call to your function, and using appropriate bounds for fitting to make sure this doesn't give a spurious fit. If your model is near the truth and your sample (I mean the cosine in your sample) is positive, then adding an absolute value around it should be a no-op (update: I realize this is never the case, see the proper approach below).

```
def f(x, Amp, n, b):

    return Amp*(np.abs(np.cos(x)))**n + b # only change here
```

With this small change I get this:

[image: result is fine]

For reference, the parameters from the fit are `(4.96482314, 2.03690954, 5.03709923])` comparing to the generation with `(5,2,5)`.

---

After giving it a bit more thought I realized that the cosine will *always* be negative for half your domain (duh). So the workaround I suggested might be a bit problematic, or at least its correctness is non-trivial. On the other hand, thinking of your original formula containing `cos(x)^n`, with negative values for `cos(x)` this only makes sense as a model if `n` is an integer, otherwise you get a complex result. Since we can't solve [Diophantine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation) fitting problems, we need to handle this properly.

The most proper way (by which I mean the way that is least likely to bias your data) is this: first do the fitting with a model that converts your data to complex numbers then takes the complex magnitude on output:

```
def f(x, Amp, n, b):

    return Amp*np.abs(np.cos(x.astype(np.complex128))**n) + b
```

This is obviously much less efficient than my workaround, since in each fitting step we create a new mesh, and do some extra work both in the form of complex arithmetic and an extra magnitude calculation. This gives me the following fit even with no bounds set:

[image: improved answer, first part]

The parameters are `(5.02849409, 1.97655728, 4.96529108)`. These are close too. However, if we put these values back into the actual model (without `np.abs`), we get imaginary parts as large as `-0.37`, which is not overwhelming but significant.

So the second step should be redoing the fit with a proper model---one that has an integer exponent. Take the exponent 2 which is obvious from your fit, and do a new fit with this model. I don't believe any other approach gives you a mathematically sound result. You can also start from the original `popt`, hoping that it's indeed close to the truth. Of course we could use the original function with some currying, but it's much faster to use a dedicated double-specific version of your model.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from matplotlib.pyplot import subplots, show

def f_aux(x, Amp, n, b):
    return Amp*np.abs(np.cos(x.astype(np.complex128))**n) + b

def f_real(x, Amp, n, b):
    return Amp*np.cos(x)**n + b


x = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, 0.01)  # pi
randomPart = np.random.rand(len(x)) - 0.5
sample = f(x, 5, 2, 5) + randomPart

fig,(frame_aux,frame) = subplots(ncols=2)
for fr in frame_aux,frame:
    fr.plot(x, sample, label="Sample measurements")
    fr.legend()
    fr.set_xlabel("x")
    fr.set_ylabel("y")

# auxiliary fit for n value
popt_aux, pcov_aux = curve_fit(f_aux, x, sample, p0=(1,1,1))

modeldata = f(x, *popt_aux)
#print(modeldata)
print('Auxiliary fit parameters: {}'.format(popt_aux))
frame_aux.plot(x, modeldata, label="Auxiliary fit")

# check visually, test if it's close to an integer, but otherwise
n = np.round(popt_aux[1])

# actual fit with integral exponent
popt, pcov = curve_fit(lambda x,Amp,b,n=n: f_real(x,Amp,n,b), x, sample, p0=(popt_aux[0],popt_aux[2]))

modeldata = f(x, popt[0], n, popt[1])
#print(modeldata)
print('Final fit parameters: {}'.format([popt[0],n,popt[1]])) 
frame.plot(x, modeldata, label="Best fit")

frame_aux.legend()
frame.legend()

show()
```

Note that I changed a few things in your code which doesn't really affect my point. The figure from the above, so the one that shows both the auxiliary fit and the proper one:

[image: final fig]

The output:

```
Auxiliary fit parameters: [ 5.02628994  2.00886409  5.00652371]
Final fit parameters: [5.0288141074549699, 2.0, 5.0009730316739462]
```

Just to reiterate: while there might be no visual difference between the auxiliary fit and the proper one, only the latter gives a meaningful answer to your problem.